# Functional API with mixed input data. Got this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer, categorical-data

I have read and search the similar question but the answers did not work for me even If I try it in several ways.

I have a data set that is this way 
4.000.000 different string representing a Cell (categorical data)
and 4.000.000 longitude, latitude, representing where those cells are
here is a snippet of the dataset ( numerical data)

```
device_id                    seconds      latitude     longitude

jg4M/taYRc2cBJPGa8c7vw==       752        53.392060    -2.069796
```

I create this model it works but i have problems when I try to fit it.
The model has a set of layers for categorical data and a separate set of layers for numerical data. And I merge them. 
All work fine until the fit part
Here is the code.

```
device_id = Input(name = 'data_tf', shape = [1,1])
visible = Input(name = 'X_train', shape=(3,1,1))

#this is the categorical layers  
top_words = 10376
embedding_vector_length = 22
x = Embedding(top_words, embedding_vector_length)(device_id)
x = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
modelx = Model(inputs=device_id, outputs = x)


#this are the numerical layers
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(visible)
hidden2 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden2)
output = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(hidden3)

modely = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)

#merge the two set of layers and all this works perfectly 
merge = concatenate([x, output], axis =1)

#layers after concatenate 

hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs=[device_id,visible], outputs=output)
```

here is a summary of the model:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
X_train (InputLayer)            (None, 3, 1, 1)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 3, 1, 10)     20          X_train[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
data_tf (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 1)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 3, 1, 20)     220         dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 1, 1, 22)     228272      data_tf[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 3, 1, 10)     210         dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1, 1, 2)      46          embedding_1[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 3, 1, 2)      22          dense_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 4, 1, 2)      0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 4, 1, 10)     30          concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 4, 1, 10)     110         dense_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)                 (None, 4, 1, 2)      22          dense_7[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 228,952
Trainable params: 228,952
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

then

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but this is the part that does not work:

```
model.fit((visible,device_id),X_trainY, batch_size=10, epochs=5, verbose=1)


AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

I have search for 4 days now similar question but none of them work for me.

Can some one help?

UPDATE 
I put the brackets as suggest below gently by Rishabh Sahrawat and have now this problem

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-9b35f717e3e7> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit([visible,device_id],X_trainY, batch_size=10, epochs=5, verbose=1)

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
     90         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     91         data = [data]
---> 92     data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
     93 
     94     if len(data) != len(names):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     90         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     91         data = [data]
---> 92     data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
     93 
     94     if len(data) != len(names):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_single_array(x)
     23                 'When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the'
     24                 'tensors to have a static batch size. '
---> 25                 'Got tensor with shape: %s' % str(shape))
     26         return x
     27     elif x.ndim == 1:

ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect thetensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 3, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not paste the full error log, from what you shared I think the problem is with the round brackets you used to input the data(categorical , numerical). 
Try with square brackets like `model.fit([visible,device_id], X_trainY, batch_size=10, epochs=5, verbose=1)`

**EDIT**

In your definition of `device_id` the shape parameter should be with round brackets instead of square brackets. Or, maybe there is a reason you can explain.

The reason behind the new error in your EDIT might be from using the layer name in the `model.fit` instead of feeding the actual data. Look [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) (skip to **Shared layers**) how and what to feed to shared layers model. Also, have a look at the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254382/valueerror-when-feeding-symbolic-tensors-to-a-model-we-expect-the-tensors-to-h).

Another thing, I found in your code is here:
`model = Model(inputs=[device_id,visible], outputs=output)`, here first, the model expects `device_id` data and then `visible` data but in your original code in `fit` you are feeding it the other way around. `model.fit((visible,device_id),X_trainY, batch_size=10, epochs=5, verbose=1)` and here `visible` and `device_id` must be actual data not layer names.

Comment: I will update my question. I did as you suggest and now I have a different error

Comment: It work. 
Thank you
But I have a new mistake 
UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported [[{{node Cast_3}}]]
is this because the device_id has to be converted to float?

Comment: Most probably yes. It sounds like the datatype is the issue. But if it still doesn’t work then maybe convert your device ids to something that is NN compatible, if you haven’t. Also, please accept the answer. Cheers!

Comment: How I do accept the answer?
I will do it but I don't know how
Apologies

Comment: On the left side of my answer, click on the tick mark and UP (^) button.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

I did and this is the answer